# Heroku Webapp Erroring on Startup

Tags: heroku, jhipster

Am getting the following error after a successful build and deploy of a JHipster microservice application onto Heroku:

```
2021-05-11T00:59:56.244858+00:00 app[web.1]: :: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.4.4 ::
2021-05-11T00:59:56.244859+00:00 app[web.1]: :: https://www.jhipster.tech ::
2021-05-11T00:59:56.244958+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-11T01:00:32.625226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/config/saathratrigateway/prod/main" host=saathratri-gateway.herokuapp.com request_id=a8dc6325-ca04-4c1c-a069-fe397dde7a82 fwd="54.227.16.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-11T01:01:12.399755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/config/saathratrigateway/prod/main" host=saathratri-gateway.herokuapp.com request_id=f19c6d78-85f8-4e2e-a721-b3f02b83e62d fwd="3.95.223.176" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-11T01:01:17.500232+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2021-05-11T01:01:17.583985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-05-11T01:01:17.754138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-05-11T01:01:17.838377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-11T01:01:19.306908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/config/saathratrigateway/prod/main" host=saathratri-gateway.herokuapp.com request_id=c89c88c7-42dd-4a88-90cf-4f12ab669559 fwd="3.95.223.176" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

My best,
Amar

Comment: You are trying to deploy a gateway application right? Which port is it supposed to use? Can you post your jhipster info output?

Comment: I got past the above error by redeploying to heroku.  The application deployed fine after I redeployed using ```jhipster heroku``` command. I do not know why it did not deploy yesterday; however, today it is deploying.